# Solution Explorer opens in Folders view

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017.

I have a project that have been working on for some months. Now all of a sudden whenever I open the solution, Solution Explorer will show it in Folders view. I have to click the following button and select the other option to show it in Solution view:

[image]

How do I restore it to the usual situation?

Comment: Just click again on the same icon it will switch back to solution view

Comment: Clicking the icon again doesn't work for me. It shows me a list of views, which contains only a folder view. I had to restart VS to get back to the default view. Looking for a non-restart method.

Answer (score 8):

In My case,

1. I opened the folder where the actual files of the project are placed in file explorer.
2. And double click on the solution file(file with extention .sln).
3. It will be opened in the usual view(Solution View)

Answer (score 3):

If you've copied a repo from github and created a solution, make sure you save once before switching to folder view. I forgot to save the newly created solution once, switched to folder view and as a result, could not get back to solution view. Very strange that my solution was somewhere in the void. I restarted VS 2017, recreated the solution and saved it.

Answer (score 2):

By clicking on the same icon has worked for me though i found my whole solution got check out.So before clicking make a note which files are actually for checkout in **TFs** .

Answer (score 1):

This was happening on one of my projects. I would change to Solution view, save/commit, but the next time I opened it, it was in Folder view again.

I don't know where the "last view" is stored, but apparently it's not in the .sln file.

I right-clicked on the solution and used Open in File Explorer, and opened the .sln file with VS Code and added a blank line at the bottom to "touch" the file. Then I reloaded and checked it in and it stuck.